# How to connect kubernetes deployment having multiple containers to multiple service ports of a single service?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a scenario like:

1. Have a single deployment containing two containers and have different ports like:

```
 template: {
  spec: {
   containers: [
     {
      name: container1,
      image: image1,
      command: [...],
      args: [...],
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent,
      ports: [
        {
          name: port1,
          containerPort: 80,
        },
      ],
      .............
    },
    {
      name: container2,
      image: image1,
      command: [...],
      args: [...],
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent,
      ports: [
        {
          name: port2,
          containerPort: 81,
        },
      ],
      ------------
    }

       ]
     }
  }
```

2. A service having multiple ports pointing to those containers like:

```
spec: {
      type: ClusterIP,
      ports: [
      {
      port: 7000,
      targetPort: 80,
      protocol: 'TCP',
      name: port1,
    },
    {
      port: 7001,
      targetPort: 81,
      protocol: 'TCP',
      name: port2,
    } 
   ]
}
```

The problem I am facing is I can connect to the container having port 80 using service name and port 7000 but I can't connect to the container having port 81 using service name and port 7001. Did I miss anything here?
Also, note that both containers have identical images having different **command** and **args** for the internal logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to re-produce this using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) and I can't. Here is my cluster config file:

```
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 30000
        hostPort: 30000
        listenAddress: 127.0.0.1

      - containerPort: 30001
        hostPort: 30001
        listenAddress: 127.0.0.1
```

then issue to create the cluster: `kind create cluster --config cluster.yaml`

Then I have a sample deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-and-wiremock
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-and-wiremock
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-and-wiremock
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
        - name: wiremock
          image: wiremock/wiremock:2.32.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

I use `nginx` and `wiremock` images, that expose different ports: `80` and `8080`. Deploy this one via : `kubectl apply -f nginx-wiremock-deployment.yaml`.

I also deploy a `service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-and-wiremock
  name: nginx-and-wiremock
spec:
  ports:
    - name: nginx
      nodePort: 30000
      targetPort: 80
      port: 80
    - name: wiremock
      nodePort: 30001
      targetPort: 8080
      port: 8080
  selector:
    app: nginx-and-wiremock
  type: NodePort
```

Once this is up and running:

```
curl localhost:30000
curl localhost:30001/__admin/mappings
```

Both of the respond just fine.

Comment: For mine, it's giving `connect ECONNREFUSED` for the container other than the 1st one. And I have used the same images on both containers. Anything I missed?

Comment: Also, curl -kv {pod_ip}:<port> is only connected to port 80.

Comment: @YashasviRajPant if you have used the _same_ images, of course those images expose the same port, 80, no? its like having two images of nginx and nginx exposes  port `80`, it does not matter what you put in `containerPort`.  makes sense?

Comment: oh ok, so any way to distinguish between them when accessing as two containers contains  different  `args` and `commands` as described above for the internal logic of image.

Comment: @YashasviRajPant you're set-up is strange, at best. If those images are run with different arguments, then they probably do different things under some conditions, so having them in the same deployment would make very little sense, to me. If they do handle some things differently, they should really be part of separate deployments. If on the other hand, this is really your case, then make the app port exposed as an environment property may be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two services or one service with two exposed ports
you can try 2 services :
with the deployment like this :

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: container1
          image:image1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
        - name: container2
          image: image1 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
```

and the services :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: container1
  annotations:
    version: v1.0
spec:
  selector:
    component: <deployment>
  ports:
     - name: container1
       port: 8080
       targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP           
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: container2
  annotations:
    version: v1.0
spec:
  selector:
    component: <deployment>
  ports:
     - name: container2
       port: 8080
       targetPort: 8081
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Actually previously we were using a single pod(deployment) for one container and we have a single service for each of them. But it seems there is a limit of pods per node in Kubernetes. 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/
So, we are trying to condense multiple containers into a single pod to save the pod limit. Is there any limit for service? If not, your solution will work.

Comment: from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/): "As many Services need to expose more than one port, Kubernetes supports multiple port definitions on a Service object". So what you say in this answer can't possibly be correct.